# Flutter build apk is not working on devices gets freeze on single screen

Tags: flutter, apk, release-mode

> I am trying to build the apk of my flutter application. The flutter run commands works fine with every build method, but when I tried to build the apk and then install it on the device the app gets freeze and I am unable to perform any actions. I have tried every possible solution.

Here is the link to detailed explanation
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64536#issuecomment-679851690

Comment: if you run `flutter logs` and lounch your app, what do you see on the logs?

Comment: Hey! @pskink logs are clear there is no error, all things are running fine, in-fact flutter run --release works fine and working but [ flutter build apk ] is not working.

Comment: so what does "not working" mean? do you see blank screen or what? what code do you run?

Comment: the app is building and installing successfully apk too, but there is only one screen visible in the release apk, which is not performing any function!